# SSL Certificates - do i need more for sub-domains?

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a commercial SSL Certificate for my website, say https://www.xyz.com
The SSL is configured in apache-vhosts.config (Apache virtual host port 443)

I am planning to introduce sub-domains like:
http://apples.xyz.com
http://oranges.xyz.com
http://mangoes.xyz.com

These will all be configured as Virtual Hosts in Apache Config.

**Question:**
Do i need to buy separate SSL Certificates for each of these sub-domains, or will my existing commercial SSL Certificate work?

Comment: You'll need to buy a cert for every subdomain, unless you paid extra for a wildcard cert for `*.xyz.com`. You **MAY** be able to get a cert that lists the subdomains as alternate names, but not all issuers support that, or will charge extra. But the alternates list is fixed at the time the cert is issued, and can't be extended later without re-issuing the cert.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the type of SSL certificate you purchased.  If you bought a wildcard SSL certificate, or one that explicitly has subdomains in it, you're probably good to go.  If you bought a cert that only has `www.xyz.com` defined, then you're not going to be able to use the same cert for the different subdomains.

If you bought for only the `www` subdomain, then depending on your server topology, you could either buy a cert for each subdomain, and use different IP for each subdomain (or if you don't care about older browsers, use [Server Name Indication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4366#section-3.1)).

My recommendation if you bought a single domain SSL cert, and you're going to have many subdomains, just to bite the bullet and buy a wildcard certificate.

Comment: As suggested a Wildcard is the simplest option but may not be cost effective. If you are only having 3/4 sub-domains it is cheaper to buy individual certs than a wildcard. Once you get to 7+ sub domains a wildcard is generally more cost effective and easier to manage.

Comment: Mathew,Andy> How do i figure out if the existing certificate i have is a Wild Card Certificate (*.xyz.com) OR only for www (www.xyz.com)?

Comment: check the the common name or CN on your certificate @Jasper